# tracert identify server that timed out

Tags: networking, command-line, traceroute

I'm experiencing some delayed responses and did a `tracert` and see a server hop is down in the middle. **How do I determine what the IP address of a timed out server on a timed out hop on a tracert?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no reliable way to find the IP address of a distant router that doesn't send ICMP TTL Exceeded messages.

Comment: There isn't, but it _might_ send those in reply to different traceroute methods, e.g. ICMP versus UDP; and even using the same method, sometimes mtr works where tracert does not.

Comment: It doesn't mean a "server hop is down." It means one of the routers along the path is not responding to ping requests. If your packet makes it to the intended destination, nothing is "down."

Comment: (1) What does this question have to do with MS-DOS?  Are you *actually* running DOS? (2) It might help us to understand your problem / question if you would post the output from ``tracert``.  (Of course you may redact sensitive information.)  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the op mistakes a window's cli for ms-dos, because of ms's marketing: MS hasn't supported DOS for decades now, and tracert is a standard cl tool in modern windows.